# jquery get works on my localhost but not the other sites

Tags: jquery, get

Hi I have a problem here
This is my code, its working when I write "http://localhost" and retrieves content but when I write other websites like "http://www.google.com" it doesn't work.
I have uploaded codes in my web host for you guys to test it.
Here is the link. http://faceproishere.netii.net/test.php
And here you can see my codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" value="http://localhost">

<input value="load" type="button" onClick="my_function()">


<textarea cols="15" rows="12" id="frame1" style="float:left"></textarea>
<div id="frame2" style="width:400px;height:400px;overflow:scroll;fl  oat:left"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function my_function()
{
    if($("#field1").val() != '' && $("#field1").val().indexOf("http",0) == 0)
    {

        $.get($("#field1").val(),function(data)
        {
            $("#frame1").html(data)
            $("#frame2").html(data)
        })

    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Tnx in advance.

Comment: Is jQuery hosted on google's cdn not supposed to be' `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access content in this way from a different source.  This is not allowed for security reasons.  See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

You can see this type of problem very easily if you check your browser's console.

Comment: Typically, you can't.  Now, there is a newer feature called CORS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control) that will work on later browsers, but only if the resource you are trying to access allows it.  If you need to access a feed, you can do so via JSON-P.  This doesn't get around the restriction directly, and is a bit of a hack.  The best thing for you to do is set up a server-side proxy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to curl though you could set up a call to curl to retrieve the data or address.

curl is a bash tool available on most Linux distributions. It can be found here http://curl.haxx.se/ .

What you do is you set up a local request trough ajax that delivers the result to a site that you fetch with curl. Curl can be called trough a shell in most scripting languages. If you have installed curl and need help with the scripting tell me what langauges and I might be abel to help.

Ok her is an explanation. It might not suit you when I did this it was in ruby sinatra wher its extreamly easy to setup paths and capture arguments of links. It could be a bit harder in php.

first of all you need some way to setup a local path that calls a php script that uses curl. The easiest way to do this is to simply add a file to your web path (depending on webserver and framework).

in the file curl_test.php you could do somthing like:

```
$response = system('curl www.google.se', $returnvalue);
echo($response)
```

You would then setup your ajax request to run that script something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "localhost/curl_test.php",
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

The trick then is how to put the right data in the data section so that you can send get variables to the curl script but ill let you solve that if you want a ruby sinatra example here is one.

```
get '/data/:brand' do
  data_link =  "https://someplace.com/brands/#{params[:brand]}"
  c = Curl::Easy.perform(data_link)
  content_type :json
  c.body_str
end
```

Comment: Yeah fortunately I have CURL in my server.Yes you can,its in php.Can you explain your idea with some codes in php language?

Comment: Please also tell me if my problem will be solved with using iframe rather than div element or not.thank you.